# Optional white space inside regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

Say I want the string "cats and dogs" and "catsanddogs" to evaluate to true against one regular expression.

```
/cats\sand\sdogs/
```

Can only evaluate to true against "cats and dogs".

```
/cats\sand\sdogs|catsanddogs/
```

This works but it seems kind of hacky. If you want to evaluate something like "cats and dogs and rabbits and mice" you can see how re-typing the string over and over is tedious.

Comment: \s* = zero or more spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/cats\s*and\s*dogs/
```

Try this.This should do it.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vN3sH3/14

or

```
/cats\s?and\s?dogs/
```

https://regex101.com/r/vN3sH3/15

Answer (score 4):

You can use a quantifier. Use `?` for 1 or 0 occurrences, and use `*` for any number (including 0) occurrences:

```
/cats\s*and\s*dogs/
```